# CFWheels form helpers vs HTML forms

Tags: html, forms, coldfusion, form-helpers, cfwheels

CFWheels has form helpers, and cfwheels.org [tries to convince me](http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-3/chapter/form-helpers-and-showing-errors) that they are better and easier to use. In the interest of being self-consistent, I would like to use them. But I'm finding that the lack of `id` attributes is making them difficult to style. For instance, because form helpers don't support the `id` tag, I can't choose when to make them visible or not, apply background images, or basically anything else I want to do with `CSS`. The control helpers do let you prepend and append to both the label and control with `div` tags if I want, but why is that easier than just surrounding them in a `div` -- which is unnecessary to do if I just use an `HTML` form. Also, that makes for unnecessarily messy rendered html.

A simple answer is "just use what works best for you." But I'm wondering if there is a good reason why I SHOULD use the form helpers, and what to do about all the styling limitations? Why the heck not just support id tags like "id" and "label-id"!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CfWheels form helpers are better. You will learn why as you try to use it in your code. And for your information, it does support id attribute, in fact, it supports all html attributes for particular element.

[Check out the text field tag](http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-3/function/textfieldtag)

for example. It clearly states that **Note: Pass any additional arguments like class, rel, and id, and the generated tag will also include those values as HTML attributes.**
So you can style them, hide them, do whatever you want to do with them using CSS, javascript, jquery.
i seriously recommend you to watch [screencasts](http://cfwheels.org/screencasts)

Comment: Also check out form object function [link](http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-3/function/category/view-helper) which helps you to bind your data to the objects and that will help you a lot of ways. It will save you a lot of coding. Also check out form association functions, they will help you a lot.

Comment: CFwheels form helpers does not support label id, so its bit difficult to style specific labels

Comment: @Keshavjha, you can give class to label by using labelClass  or label id to label by using labelId and then you can use that class/id to style your label.

Comment: nice to know that. i will test it

Comment: Don't forget you can set the default settings for form helpers in config/settings.cfm  - saves a lot of repetition.

Comment: Thanks!  I just looked at the supported parameters in the box. I didn't read the text above it.

Comment: @Keshavjha, I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: @Tushar, I didn't know about labelClass and labelID! Why don't they put those in the documentation? I assume they override a class or id I would specify as an attribute, for instance, #textField(class="control-class", labelClass="label-class")#.

Comment: @abalter, Documentation will be always remain short to our expectations that i have learned as i went through documentations of many languages. Believe me, documentation of CfWheels is far better than anything out there. You always have to experiments to find out nuances of any technology. That being said, no it won't override. As from your example from your comment, class **control-class** will be applied to your **text field** and class **label-class** will be applied to the **label of the text field**. So you can use both and apply separate styles to label and text field. Hope this helps.